# Boost.Type_erasure: member function return _self

Tags: c++, boost, boost-type-erasure

I want to use Boost.Type_erasure on a member function that returns the type itself. With `_self` as the return type, it is OK. However, when the **return type** changes to `pair<_self, some_type>`, an error occurs. The following code reproduces the problem.

```
#include <utility>
#include <boost/type_erasure/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/member.hpp>

BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((HasTest1), Test1, 0)
BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((HasTest2), Test2, 0)

using boost::type_erasure::_self;
using std::pair;
using Type1 = boost::type_erasure::any<
    boost::mpl::vector<
    boost::type_erasure::copy_constructible<>,
    HasTest1<_self(), _self const>
    >,
    _self
>;
using Type2 = boost::type_erasure::any<
    boost::mpl::vector<
    boost::type_erasure::copy_constructible<>,
    HasTest2<pair<_self, int>(), _self const>
    >,
    _self
>;

int main() {
    struct test {
        test Test1() const { throw; }
        pair<test, int> Test2() const { throw; }
    };

    Type1{ test{} };// OK
    Type2{ test{} };// Error
    // Type2{ test{} }.Test2().first.Test2();// Expected to work
}
```

How can I fix this problem without using return arguments?

Sample error message:

```
main.cpp:6:1: error: no viable conversion from 'pair<test, [...]>' to 'pair<boost::type_erasure::_self, [...]>'

BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((HasTest2), Test2, 0)

^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You should probably ask on the boost mailing list, the author of the library is usually pretty fast to answer any question. If you want something that seems to work (via trial and error) take a look at [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65f19ed624b8c996).

Comment: @cv_and_he Thank you. Your code passes the compilation. But the resulting object cannot call Test2().

Comment: Keep in mind that I have no idea at all of what I am doing, but [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e736663ff8daf4b) does not fail (yet).

Comment: @cv_and_he Never mind. I've posted the problem to the boost mailling list. But the code you provided still doesn't work. `terminate called without an active exception'

Comment: Because your `Test2` method throws... [The next problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a21ec21653ba11f5). I hope you get a real answer on the mailing list because it is interesting.

Comment: @cv_and_he Oh, I'd been fool. Yet, the code doesn't fit the requirement. You may test `t.Test2().first.Test2();`. The type returned by Test2() is expected to be `pair<Type2, int>`.

Comment: Look at the edit in my previous comment. You could probably get a `first` and `second` by specializing `concept_interface`, but probably my initial approach wasn't the best.

Comment: @cv_and_he Your edited code indeed work. However, it doesn't fit the primary intention of using `type_erasure`, i.e. I don't care about the real type of the `.first`. Your advice should work, and I believe it is not optimal. The return type should better be `pair<any, int>` instead of `any` that binds to `pair<test, int>`.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the response from Steven Watanabe.

*The library can only handle placeholders at the top level.  There is no way to handle the general case, `X<_self>` automatically. This is essentially the same as covariant return types for virtual functions, which have similar restrictions.*

*To get the effect that you want, you'll need to define the `concept_interface` manually.*

Alternatively, I use `boost::any` to work around.

```
#include <utility>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/member.hpp>

BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((HasTest), Test, 0)

using Type = boost::type_erasure::any<
    boost::mpl::vector<
    boost::type_erasure::copy_constructible<>,
    HasTest<boost::any()>
    >
>;

int main() {
    struct TestType {
        auto Test() {
            return std::make_pair(0, Type{ *this });
        }
    };
    auto obj = Type{ TestType{} }.Test();
    boost::any_cast<std::pair<int, Type>&>(obj).second.Test();
}
```